# Perf record hanging on armv7

Tags: linux, arm, perf

I have a device with embedded Linux. The base image is built using ptxdist 2019.01 with the OSELAS toolchain build 2018.02 with gcc 7.3.1. Ptxdist has native option to enable perf support, so I enabled it and installed it on the device. It is using Linux 4.19.72.

However, when I run `perf record -g` (with process to trace) without explicitly specifying events, it seems to hang using a lot of CPU and not responding to SIGINT. I am not sure what the default event is; it does not seem to say anywhere. How can I find what it is hanging on and/or which events to specify that will actually work?

Update #1: Trying to `strace perf recorg -g app…` shows (

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "0\n", 1024)                    = 2
geteuid32()                             = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
statfs64("/sys", 88, 0xbef2f388)        = 0
stat64("/sys/bus/event_source/devices/cs_etm/format", 0xbef2f440) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/sys/bus/event_source/devices/cs_etm/type", 0xbef2f440) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/system/cpu", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3, /* 12 entries */, 32768)  = 360
getdents64(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat64("/sys/bus/event_source/devices/arm_spe_0/format", 0xbef2f440) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/sys/bus/event_source/devices/arm_spe_0/type", 0xbef2f440) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
geteuid32()                             = 0
perf_event_open(
```

Unfortunately arguments of the `perf_event_open` don't ever get written out. Listing with ps shows it in `R` state.

Comment: You could `strace perf ...` to see what system calls it made; maybe knowing which PAPI syscall its inside would help?  Or if it's making tons of syscalls.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it hangs in `perf_event_open`. Unfortunately strace does not print the arguments when the call never completes.